# is there a way to select row or column table in Word document VSTO C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have a table in Word document. I want to able to select a row or column or only a cell or whole table to modify.
now I can select the complete table and modify all cells, but I can not select a single row or column or cell.
I can not create a range for this purpose.
below my code for select whole of table:

```
if (WordAddIn.Config.ApplicationConfig.TemplateLanguage.ValueToShare == true)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= WordManager.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= WordManager.Selection.Tables[1].Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                           ...
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            { }
                        }
                    }
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Create a macro of what you need. Look at the VB calls of the macro and mimic/use those calls in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the index of your table/row/column, but this is how you get the reference to each. From there, you can edit, delete, add, etc.

```
       Word.Table myTable = Globals.ThisDocument.Tables[0];
       //Get Row
       Word.Row myRow = myTable.Rows[0];
       //Get Column
       Word.Column myCOl = myTable.Columns[0];
       //Get Cell
       int rowNum = 0;
       int colNum = 0;
       Word.Cell myCell = myTable.Cell(rowNum, colNum);
```